# Dplyr Summarize: Combining values for certain groups

Tags: r, dplyr

I have data on hospital admissions per patients. I am trying add up the price of care for patients that were re-admitted to hospital within 5 days.

This is an example dataset:

```
(
    dt <- data.frame(
        id         = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4),
        admit_date = c(1, 9, 5, 9, 10, 20),
        price      = c(10, 20, 20, 30, 15, 16)
    )
)

#   id admit_date price
# 1  1          1    10
# 2  1          9    20
# 3  2          5    20
# 4  2          9    30
# 5  3         10    15
# 6  4         20    16
```

And this is what I have tried so far:

```
library(dplyr)

# 5-day readmission:
dt %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    arrange(id, admit_date)%>%
    mutate(
        duration = admit_date - lag(admit_date),
        readmit = ifelse(duration < 6, 1, 0)
        ) %>%
    group_by(id, readmit) %>%           # this is where i get stuck
    summarize(sumprice = sum(price)) 

# # A tibble: 6 × 3
# # Groups:   id [4]
#      id readmit sumprice
#   <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1     1       0       20
# 2     1      NA       10
# 3     2       1       30
# 4     2      NA       20
# 5     3      NA       15
# 6     4      NA       16
```

And this is what I would like to have:

```
#   id sum_price
# 1  1        10
# 2  1        20
# 3  2        50
# 4  3        15
# 5  4        16
```

Comment: Is the date field really numbers? Of would this ideally be date-type? It would definitely change the answer a bit. This [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68894318/dplyr-summarize-combining-values-for-certain-groups) should help if it will be a date-type field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the difference in days, between *adjacent* visits is greater than 5 - return `TRUE` if not - return `FALSE` (`-Inf > 5` is `FALSE` for the first day, thus `lag`s default is `Inf`). After that, for each individual we take a cumulative sum to label the groups. We finally summarize within each individual, using this `cumsum` as a grouping variable for `by`:

```
dt |>
    group_by(id) |>
    arrange(id, admit_date) |>
    summarise(
        sum_price = by(
            price, 
            cumsum((admit_date - lag(admit_date, , Inf)) > 5), 
            sum
            )
        ) |>
    ungroup()

# # A tibble: 5 × 2
#      id sum_price
#   <dbl> <by>     
# 1     1 10       
# 2     1 20       
# 3     2 50       
# 4     3 15       
# 5     4 16
```

Answer (score -1):

So, you want (at most) one row per patient in the final dataframe, so you should group on just `id`.

Then, for each patient, you should calculate if that patient has `any` row with `readmit==`).

Finally, you filter out any patient that wasn't readmitted from your summarized dataframe.

Putting it all together, it might look like:

```
dt %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  arrange(id, admit_date) %>%
  mutate(duration = admit_date - lag(admit_date),
         readmit = ifelse(duration < 6, 1, 0)) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%  # group by just 'id' to get one row per patient
  summarize(sumprice = sum(price, na.rm = T),
            is_readmit = any(readmit == 1)) %>%  # If patient has any 'readmit' rows, count the patient as a readmit patient
  filter(is_readmit) %>%  # Filter out any non-readmit patients
  select(-is_readmit)  # get rid of the `is_readmit` column
```

Which should result in:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 3
     id sumprice is_readmit
  <dbl>    <dbl> <lgl>     
1     2       50 TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks,  but this wasn't exactly what I needed. I wanted to add the price for patients that had close readmissions only.